# How do I pass an argument to referenced function without invoking it using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reference, arguments

I want my code to be something like `el.onclick = someFunc(arg)`, however, someFunc is invoked on load. How would I go about passing an argument to a function that I want to reference, without also invoking it?

Comment: You must wrap the function call within another function that will serve as the main event handler.

Comment: You can check my answer also :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following 3 ways,

1. Using `addEventListener`

```js
var elm = document.getElementById('testButton');

elm.addEventListener('click', function(){
    someFunc('testArg');
});

function someFunc(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

```html
<input id="testButton" type="button" value="Click"  />
```

2. Using `onclick` and `bind`

```js
function someFunc(arg) {
   console.log(arg);
}

var elm = document.getElementById('testButton');
elm.onclick = someFunc.bind(null, 'testArg');
```

```html
<input id="testButton" type="button" value="Click" />
```

3. Using `onclick` and function wrapper,

```js
function someFunc(arg) {
  return function() {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}

var elm = document.getElementById('testButton');
elm.onclick = someFunc('testArg');
```

```html
<input id="testButton" type="button" value="Click"  />
```

**Note**: Option 1 with `addEventListener` is the best one to use among the options above but other options (1 & 2) can be considered in case of option 1 is not doable.

For an instance, you can use `onclick` and `bind` when you need to reuse the same method for multiple elements and have to use the element inside the method with `this` as below.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   var button = buttons[i];
   button.onclick = someFunc.bind(button, 'testArg');
}

// Assume this function is in another file
function someFunc(arg) {
   console.log(this.id + ': '+ arg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="testButton1" type="button" value="Click" />
  <input id="testButton2" type="button" value="Click" />
  <input id="testButton3" type="button" value="Click" />
  <input id="testButton4" type="button" value="Click" />
  <input id="testButton5" type="button" value="Click" />
</div>
```

Comment: Choices #1 and #2 are extreme overkill. #3 is the best choice.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes agreed `addEventListener` is the best but given other choices to select based on the situation

Comment: Good to know, though.

Comment: @JonathanReiser Yes you are right as you can choose one of them based on the need and situation :-)

Comment: It would have been a better answer to show #3 solution first and explain that it is the simplest (and probably best) solution for the question, then show the other two and explain when they might be applicable. Remember, SO is a knowledge base for future questions as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your comments and I have updated the same :-)

Comment: Still would be best to explain when exactly you might want options 2 and 3.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Have updated a case for option 2. Will update for option 3.

Comment: I think your #2 scenario is pretty contrived. If you got the buttons and looped them like this: `document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(...);`, you could bind an event handler to each button just using `this`. And, you could get the clicked button reference in the event handler with `evt.target`.

Comment: I have mentioned this in a comment saying `// Assume this function is in another file`. So this will be useful in complex cases.

Comment: Why/how would that change anything?

Comment: The complex scenario will go bigger to explain. I will explain you a sample scenario later which I encountered in SO longtime ago and will search the same :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `addEventListener` to add the event click. The `addEventListener` method attaches an event handler to the specified element. You need to pass the callback, which would be invoked when the event occurs.

```
movieElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    showDescription(arg);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! I tried using addEventListener originally, but I did not wrap my function in an anonymous function, this did it though. Thank you.